# AJAX ResponseText as DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

Consider the following function using jQuery:

```
function getVal() {
    jQuery.get('/relative/url/', function (data) {
        return data.getElementById('myInput').value;
    }
}
```

This is basically what I want to do, but I have no idea how it should be done.
The only methods I know would work involve frames or innerHTML which I can't use because I have to wait for the element to be ready. The only way to do that is to use a callback, and this function *must* return the value of the element rather than something else.
My logic is likely faulty here, so please feel free to correct me.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do in detail, because the code is not really accomplishing anything?

Comment: You can use a synchronous call, but that makes for a poor interface. Your design is faltered if you think it "needs" to return the value. You're not utilising the asynchronous nature of javascript.

Comment: you are returning html into a string (data)?? or dara is an json?

Comment: It's HTML to be added into an array as part of an object.
var data_obj = [];
data_obj.push({
"obj_name":getVal
});

It's one of several other objects that all need to be added at the same time to the array so that they only take up one element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, alright. I've got it. I don't think I provided enough information. I assumed context was irrelevant. Alright, here's an example depicting my solution.

```
function getVal() {
    $.get('/relative/url/', function (data) {
        $.get('relative/url/2', function (data2) {
            var data_obj = [];
            data_obj.push({
                "data_1":data[i].name
            }, {
                "data_2":$(data).find('#myInput').val()
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, with your current structure you should use a callback to return the value. To parse the HTML string retrieved via AJAX, you can hand it to jQuery and then query it just as usual.

```
function getVal(callback) {
    jQuery.get('/relative/url/', function (data) {
        callback($(data).find('#myInput').val());
    }, 'html');
}
```

Then, when you are calling the function `getVal`, you'll need to provide a callback:

```
getVal(function(input_val) {
    /**
     * This code will be run once the GET request finishes.
     * It will be passed one parameter - the value of #myInput in the HTML
     * response to the request (see getVal function).
     */

    alert(input_val);
});
```

Comment: according to his post, p looks for an element with the id "myInput", not a myInput element

Comment: $(data).find() is exactly what I was trying to find. I'm not sure why I didn't think of it. Other than that, I still can't return the value this way. I could use a global variable and wait for it to change, I guess, but that's really messy. I can alert($(data).find('#myInput').val()); with no trouble.

Comment: Hi Newton, I added a usage sample. If you try something like that do you see the alert box with the expected value?

Comment: Yes. $(data).find('#myInput').val() works for my purposes. It's the return that I'm unable to pull off in my scenario.

Comment: The callback example I added doesn't work for you? If you provide `getVal` with a function that accepts one parameter, that function should be called once the GET request has finished and the value of the field is fetched.

Comment: It works, but I can't pull off a return. My setup is as follows:
var data_obj = []; data_obj.push({"obj_name":data[index].name}, {"obj_data":getVal()});

Comment: Due to the asynchronous nature of that second data fetch, you'll need to restructure a bit. Maybe: `getVal(function(input_value) { data_obj.push({'obj_name': data[index].name}, {'obj_data': input_value}); });`

Comment: I can't do that because data[index].name is the result of a separate AJAX call. That's the entire problem.

Comment: Ah, in that case I think it'd be best to use a global counter like `num_requests_left`, storing the results in variables outside the scope of the AJAX callbacks. Once `num_requests_left` is 0 grab all the variables and continue with your already-written code. If you need further help please contact me at spam.me@engel.uk.to — it might be a bit difficult to explain in single-line comments :)

Comment: I've got it figured out, thanks to you. I'll post my answer once I'm allowed.

Answer (score 0):

No, you could not do that.. since it is ansync call. What you need is to provide a callback to you code, to return the value

```
function getVal(callback) {
    jQuery.get('/relative/url/', function (data) {
        callback(data.getElementById('myInput').value);
    }
}

getVal(function (value) {
  alert(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if the it's valid html markup, you can use browse its xml with the selector:

```
*[id=myInput]
```

or you can just render the markup on some dummy element in your page and then do you lookup:

```
function getVal() {
    jQuery.get('/relative/url/', function (data) {
        dummyNode.innerHTML = data; //not sure data points to responseTxt
        return getElementById('myInput').innerHTML;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that unless the elements are added to dom tree.

```
function getVal() {
    jQuery.get('/relative/url/', function (data) {
        return $(document.body).append(data).find('#myInput').val();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several problems there. First, you cannot `return` from a callback like that. You would just return to the anonymous function itself, not from the `getVal()` method.

To solve that, you can return the `jXHR` object and apply some magic:

```
function getVal() {
    return jQuery.get('/relative/url/');
}

getVal().done(function (data) {
    var val = $( data ).find('#myInput').val();
    // do something with val
}
```

I don't know how the structure from `data` looks like, but it should work that way. If not, its probably because of `myInput` is on the top level. In that case, replace `.find()` with `.filter()`.